# Girando los valores de un array multidimensional PHP

Tags: php

estoy haciendo un ejercicio para clase en el que me piden crear una tabla de nxn con ciertos requisitos, en la diagonal se mostrarán asteriscos, en la parte de arriba se mostrará la suma de las posiciones de las filas y columnas, y abajo se mostrarán numeros aleatorios entre el 10 y el 20, y luego tengo que crear una función que invierta estos valores, pero el programa no es capaz de hacerlo con mas de 13filasx13columnas, a ver si alguien puede ayudarme, ya que no veo el error, a mis ojos el código está correcto y el profesor tampoco ha sabido encontrar nada...

```
<?php
function creaMatriu($n){
    echo "Matriu";
    for ($fila = 0; $fila < $n; $fila++){
        for ($columna = 0; $columna < $n; $columna++){
            if ($fila == $columna){
                $matriu[$fila][$columna] = "*";
            }elseif ($fila > $columna){
                $matriu[$fila][$columna] = mt_rand(10,20);
            }else{
                $matriu[$fila][$columna] = $columna + $fila;
            }

        }
    }
    mostraMatriu($matriu, $n);
    echo "Matriu girada";
    giraMatriu($matriu, $n);
}

function mostraMatriu($matriu, $n)
{
    echo "<table border = 1 width=400>";
    for ($fila = 0; $fila < $n; $fila++) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($columna = 0; $columna < $n; $columna++) {
            if ($fila == $columna) {
                echo "<td align='center'>";
                echo $matriu[$fila][$columna];
                echo "</td>";
            } elseif ($fila > $columna) {
                echo "<td align='center'>";
                echo $matriu[$fila][$columna];
                echo "</td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td align='center'>";
                echo $matriu[$fila][$columna];
                echo "</td>";
            }

        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<br>";
}

function giraMatriu($matriu, $n){
    for ($fila = 0; $fila < $n; $fila++){
        for ($columna = 0; $columna < $n; $columna++){
            if ($fila == $columna){
                $matriuGirada[$fila][$columna] = "*";
            }elseif ($fila > $columna){
                $matriuGirada[$fila][$columna] = $matriu[$columna][$fila];
            }else{
                $matriuGirada[$fila][$columna] = $matriu[$columna][$fila];
            }
        }
    }
    mostraMatriu($matriuGirada,$n);
}

creaMatriu(16);
?>
```

Comment: Tu código funciona a la perfección. Puedes ver [la demo aquí](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2y8n-5y7x)

Comment: Oye, pues es cierto... Igual es problema del intérprete o un problema de memoria... Muchas gracias!